# Logstash missing class name (`org.apache.http.─▒mpl.client.StandardHttpRequestRetryHandler')

Tags: java, windows, logstash

I want to use logstash to fetch data from rabitmq on windows but when I start logstash with even empty input and output I get missing class name `org.apache.http.─Impl.client.StandardHttpRequestRetryHandler` error.

On cmd I run:

```
C:\ELK_Stack\logstash\bin>logstash -e input {stdin {}}output {stdout {}} --debug
```

but I get

> [ERROR] 2018-10-28 23:29:38.504 [main] Logstash - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (NameError) missing class name (org.apache.http.─▒mpl.client.StandardHttpRequestRetryHandler)

Answer (score 3):

problem was seem by region because of this, I had changed 
`jvm.options`from`logstash\config`

then I set

```
## Locale
# Set the locale language
#-Duser.language=en

# Set the locale country
#-Duser.country=US
```

to this

```
# Set the locale language
-Duser.language=en

# Set the locale country
-Duser.country=US
```

then  and it solved my problem

Comment: Thnx Bro! Simple Solution

Comment: @ÖmerÇANGA Even if I changed it, I still got the issue.

Answer (score 2):

problem was seem my region but even I changed my region it did not change anything and I found `StandardHttpRequestRetryHandler` in  `client.rb` file

and

changed `'Java::OrgApacheHttpImplClient::StandardHttpRequestRetryHandler'`  to `'Java::OrgApacheHttp.impl.client::StandardHttpRequestRetryHandler'` and it solved my problem

Comment: @Andorid Even if I changed it , I still got the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CentOS 8, the path for solution is:

```
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/manticore-0.8.0-java/lib/manticore/client.rb
```

And you should change this:

```
"OrgApacheHttpImplClient" ==> "OrgApacheHttp.impl.client"
```